# Storing values using if inside while loop BASH

Tags: linux, bash, apache-spark, while-loop

I am working with a new script that reads from a log file and then stores the ips which match one of the two patterns:
Either its a failed attempt or its a failed attempt using ssh.

My code runs good, but the problem is that when the while condition finishes, when I want to call the variable which stores all the IPs it only shows the last one.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=";" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
    first=$(echo $p | sed -E -e "s/[[:blank:]]+/;/g" | cut -d ";" -f 6)
    if [[ $first == "Failed" ]];
    then
        echo "ADVERTENCIA - ATAC DDOS - !"
        x="$(echo $p | sed -E -e "s/[[:blank:]]+/;/g" | awk -F ";" '{print $11}') "
    elif [[ $first == "pam_unix(sshd:auth):" ]];
    then
        echo "ADVERTENCIA - LOGUEIG DE SSH - ! !"
        y="$(echo $p | sed -E -e "s/[[:blank:]]+/;/g" | awk -F ";" '{print $15}' | cut -b 7-19)" 
    fi
done < syslog.txt
(IFS=""; sort <<< "$x") | uniq -c
#This comand only prints the last ip, but I want to print the whole IP list.
```

My syslog text:

```
Apr 15 00:00:11 spark sshd[7812]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.25.208.92 user=root

Apr 15 11:38:58 spark sshd[13924]: Failed password for root from 183.3.202.111 port 22064 ssh2

Apr 15 11:38:58 spark sshd[13924]: Failed password for root from 183.3.202.111 port 22064 ssh2
Apr 15 00:00:11 spark sshd[7812]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.25.208.92 user=root
```

Current output:

```
1 183.3.202.111
1 218.25.208.92
```

What it should be really printing:

```
2 183.3.202.111
2 218.25.208.92
```

Comment: Is the simplified version of your question "Why does `x=foo; x=bar; echo $x` only show `bar` and not also `foo`?"

Answer (score 2):

Each time you assign a value to `x` you're overwriting the previous version:

```
x="$(echo $p | sed -E -e "s/[[:blank:]]+/;/g" | awk -F ";" '{print $11}') "
```

Assuming your intention is to append new ip's onto the end of `x`, you have a few options, eg:

```
# use "+=" to append to variable

x+="$(echo $p | sed -E -e "s/[[:blank:]]+/;/g" | awk -F ";" '{print $11}') "

# reference variable in the assignment, eg, x="${x}..."

x="${x}$(echo $p | sed -E -e "s/[[:blank:]]+/;/g" | awk -F ";" '{print $11}') "
```